# ios calendar event from website ics

Tags: ios, calendar

I have a page where I have a link with an ics file.

Using safari the problem is that when downloading and importing the event into the calendar is showing the wrong event, precissely an old one.

The strange situation of this is that obviously some cache or trace from the old file is getting gathered instead of the new ics file, more strange to me at least is the fact that I deleted everything like cache history, calendar entries, etc. , even changed the URL to an invalid one and then does nothing, and the correct one still remains with the old event information from 3 months old.

I tried searching here and internet about reason of this behaviour but I havent find any logical reason.

I also changed all settings under icloud and under Mail,contacts, Calendars without success.

Does anyone knows about this weird behaviour Im facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved my problem.

The issue was the UID on the .ics. Needs to be Unique and I had it repeated.

Probably is a "stupid" reason but got me crazy. I leave this for someone who would have this kind of "stupid" issue in the future.